# Elastic search how to create a live search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search and playing around with in it.
I created an index called live_search_index
then I add documents contain these title fields.

- Western province
- Northern province
- Colombo district
- Colombo city
- Negambo city

If I run this query

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "colombo"
    }
}
}
```

If I run this query I will get `colombo district` and `colombo city`
But this query gives me nothing.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "mbo"
    }
}
}
```

What I want is pass "mbo" and get the result of

Colo**mbo** district

Colo**mbo** city

Nega**mbo** city

How do I achieve this using elastic search?

Comment: You can index the terms using ngrams
See this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [Wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) query instead of match as you did.

```
{
    "query": {
    "wildcard": {
         "title": "*mbo"
     }
     }
}
```

Comment: Avoid beginning patterns with * or ?. This can increase the iterations needed to find matching terms and slow search performance. [ref](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html#:~:text=Avoid%20beginning%20patterns%20with%20*%20or%20%3F.%20This%20can%20increase%20the%20iterations%20needed%20to%20find%20matching%20terms%20and%20slow%20search%20performance.)